# When is a ruled patch free of planar points?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

Let $I,J$ be open intervals. Let $\gamma$ and $w$ be two unit-speed curves $I \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$. In particular, assume that, for every $t \in I$,

- $w(t) \cdot w(t) =1$,
- $w(t) \neq \pm \gamma'(t)$,
- $\gamma''(t) \neq 0$.

I am interested in finding conditions on $\gamma$ so that the (image of the) map $\sigma \colon I \times J \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$,

$$\sigma(t,u) = \gamma(t)+uw(t),$$

which is clearly regular (i.e., immersive) in a neighborhood of $\gamma(I)$, has no planar point. I suspect that choosing $\gamma$ so that its torsion is never zero (or at most only at isolated points) will be sufficient. Can anybody confirm so? Is there a way to prove it without getting into tedious calculations? By planar point I mean of course a point where both principal curvatures vanish.

Comment: I don't think torsion of $\gamma$ has anything to do with it; that would involve $\gamma'''$. Now, if you restrict to smooth surfaces with $K=0$ then there won't be planar points generically unless you have a plane (cones, cylinders, and you've ruled out tangent developables).

Comment: But at isolated points you're going to have some horrible equation involving the first two derivatives of each of $\gamma$ and $w$ together with a quadratic expression in $u$, *along with* the more natural "developing" condition $w'(t)\cdot \gamma'(t)\times w(t) = 0$ (which says that the tangent plane stays constant along the particular ruling at instant $t$).